# How display currency with Freemarker when using Longs

Tags: java, freemarker

So let's say I have:

```
class Person
{
    private long salary;
}
```

Where 5345273 would be equal to $53,452.73 (in other words the last two digits are the cents.

Is there a way to directly reference `${Person.salary}` so that it displays the proper amount?

I did see that there are [pre-defined formats such as Currency](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html) but there doesn't appear to be one if you use longs. I did see it was possible to [create your own custom formatter](http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_config_custom_formats.html) but is this the only way? And if so is there anyone who already created one because I can't imagine I'm the only person using long to manage currency amounts. And also is that the correct solution?

Comment: The question is somewhat misleading as being `long` is not really relevant. What's relevant that you store the amount in cents, but want to show it in dollars. So it's unit conversion, not just mere formatting. Anyway, if you can't change the data-model, I think using a custom format is the cleanest solution you can get.

Comment: @ddekany My concern is if that I use doubles I will run into precision issues due to conversions. In other words I might lose the odd cent here and there which is not acceptable for accounting data...

Comment: For money, you should use `BigDecimal`-s. Double-s/floats are rather for physical simulations and games and such.

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible to convert the long to a double in the expression. Something like this: `${(Person.salary/100)?string.currency}`

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that because it's really a workaround and if a non-IT person has to implement the template it will be very odd...

Comment: In my opinion the oddity resides in storing salary in cents, you could add a `float getSalaryInDollars()` to the model and express your currency as @henrik suggests with `{person.salaryInDollars?string.currency}`